# My inheritance don't show in another page

Tags: python, web, flask, jinja2

I've created a code for test inheritance in Flask + Jinja2, but, this method isn't working.

I have 2 files, an "index.html" and "leftBar.html".

The codes are below.

**index.html**

```
<html>
<body>
{% block leftbar %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

**leftbar.html**

```
{% extends 'index.html' %}
{% block leftbar %}
<b>This is my left bar!</b>
{% endblock %}
```

Actually, nothing happens when I execute.

Comment: did you run it in console/terminal/cmd.exe to see error message ? do you run it in debug mode - `app(debug=True)` ? How do you use this template in code ? Did you put HTML in correct subfolder ?

Comment: What is the output that you *do* get? Are you getting any HTML at all?